# Redirect www & non-www to non-www subfolder permanent

Tags: .htaccess

As a way of changing my document root, I'm trying to perform a redirect in htaccess.

**This redirects to /subfolder without it showing in the url but doesnt remove www**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule (.*) /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

How would I go about redircting `www` and `non-www` to `non-www.domain/subfolder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a specific rule to redirect, it needs to be before your routing rule. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule (.*) /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What if you have tens or hundreds of subfolders? Should you list each one? Is there no way to write this in uniform way?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov this obviously isn't suited for multiple folders. How would you even know what request to route to what sub folder? The problem you're trying to solve would be completely different.

Comment: @JonLin Could you recommend how to do this for nginx?